# Spring Boot Build failed : Cannot find JAR 'aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.948.jar'

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle

I'm trying to run spring boot project, but i get this error.

any idea what error is this ?

```
Cannot find JAR 'aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.948.jar' required by module 'gradle-resources-s3' using classpath or distribution directory '/home/mbunderline76/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-7.3.2-bin/4k4cn06q0rruwh9dpndf9gmi8/gradle-7.3.2'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add dependency for the jar required by your gradle version. Trying adding this dependency and refreshing your gradle.

`implementation group: 'com.amazonaws', name: 'aws-java-sdk-core', version: '1.11.948'`

or

```
implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:1.11.948'
```

Comment: I still get the same error, I can't rebuild project!

Comment: @MohammadBaqer Did you have refreshed or update your build.gradle file?

Comment: what do you mean by refresh? you mean 'Run appName [dependencies]'?

Comment: No, Just go to your build.gradle file right-click and go to Gradle and there is option for Refresh Gradle Project.

Comment: @MohammadBaqer Also, in your project there is build.gradle file there you need to the dependency.

Answer (score 0):

Running on M1 Mac with Kotlin, Adding

```
configurations.all {
resolutionStrategy {
    force ("software.amazon.awssdk.crt:aws-crt:0.16.12")
    }
}
```

to the build.gradle.kts file (don't forget to refresh) worked for me as a work around per this(https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-kotlin/issues/473) github issue